# eliminate all URLs via regular expression matching replace with generic word URL

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am new to regular expressions matching. Suppose i want to find all URL  in a text file separated by commas and replace them with with word "url".

```
user,user,' http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - awww, that\'s a bummer.    you shoulda got david carr of third day to do it. ;d',0   
user,user,'is upset that he can\'t update his facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result  school today also. blah!',0   
user,user,' i dived many times for the ball. http://twitpic.com/2y1zl managed to save 50\%  the rest go out of bounds',0  
user,user,'my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire ',0  
user,user,' no, it\'s not behaving at all. i\'m mad. why am i here? because i can\'t see you all over there. ',0  
user,user,' not the whole crew ',0   
user,user,'need a hug ',0   
user,user,' hey  long time no see! yes.. rains a bit ,only a bit  lol , i\'m fine thanks , how\'s you ?',0    
user,user,'_k nope they didn\'t have it ',0   
user,user,'que me muera ? ',0   
user,user,'spring break in plain city... it\'s snowing ',0  
user,user,'i just re-pierced my ears ',0
```

**Wish to achieve an output this way**

```
user,user,' *url*- awww, that\'s a bummer.    you shoulda got david carr of third day to do it. ;d',0   
user,user,'is upset that he can\'t update his facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result  school today also. blah!',0   
user,user,' i dived many times for the ball. *url* managed to save 50\%  the rest go out of bounds',0  
user,user,'my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire ',0  
user,user,' no, it\'s not behaving at all. i\'m mad. why am i here? because i can\'t see you all over there. ',0  
user,user,' not the whole crew ',0   
user,user,'need a hug ',0   
user,user,' hey  long time no see! yes.. rains a bit ,only a bit  lol , i\'m fine thanks , how\'s you ?',0    
user,user,'nope they didn\'t have it ',0   
user,user,'que me muera ? ',0   
user,user,'spring break in plain city... it\'s snowing ',0  
user,user,'i just re-pierced my ears ',0
```

I have tried sed

```
sed -e 's/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$//URL/' filename.txt  |less
```

find and replace regular expressions does not  work

Comment: I am not sure about how replace in sed works, but your regex to catch the URLs could only be, (^http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/\w+$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default GNU sed regular expressions require a lot of backslashes (ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes). Also, sed regexes don't understand the perl `\d` and `\w`.

Matching URLs is a pretty hard problem. Start with

```
sed  's@https\?://[^[:blank:]]\+@*url*@g' file
```

This uses an alternate delimiter for the `s///` command to avoid needing to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if your URLs are seperated from anything that follows by spaces or anything that cannot be in an URL.

I didn't take care of non-http URLs or user/password combinations here; just an http/https followed by a sequence of characters, allowed in an URL.

```
sed -e 's@https\?://[][0-9a-Z._~:/?#@!$&()*+,;=%'\''-]\+@URL@g'
```

- I used `@` as delimiter character to ease handling of slashes.
- As square brackets and dashes are allowed, I put those directly at the start and the end of the character class respectively.
- to catch the single quote, this has to be first inserted literally and then escaped inside, so it ends up being: `'\''`

Comment: Obviously, if blanks are delimiters, the solution of @glenn-jackman is to be preferred.